# How make CSS Simple ProgressBar with icons (just view to show)?

Tags: html, css, icons, progress-bar, ratingbar

I need to show a progress bar like this picture;

PICTURE: http://i12.photobucket.com/albums/a244/yanyzx01/bar_zpscrqvn78g.jpg

(static 15 hexagon icons)

Is not required to change the colored area on clicks or throw the time, is just see the static progress defined.

I required to use the icon "hexagon" from https://materialdesignicons.com/ this way:

```
<i class="mdi mdi-hexagon"></i>
```

I was thinking to try a background who with the attribute witdh: x% define the colored zone. By example: 45%.
One I saw this in a stars example but i did find it again :'c

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be by having a png image with black background and transparent hexagons.

```
<div class="wrapper" style="position:relative">
  <div id="bar" style="background: red; position:absolute; width: 0%"></div>
  <div id="image" style="background:url('path/to/img')"></div>
</div>
```

Then on javascript increase the width of `#bar` width depending on the ongoing process.